# Access URL or headers in client component rendered on server, (nextjs, app router)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Currently using nextjs 13+ with server components and app router.

I have a use case where I'd like to access either the url path or a header inside a client component BUT during its rendering on the **server side**. It has to be a client component because it contains state, but client components can't access headers or requests (as far as i'm aware). But it seems silly to me that I can't accecss these things while it's being rendered on the server, because the server will already have all of this information available to it.

Thanks!